# wordpress database (wp_post_meta) structure efficiency

Tags: mysql, database, performance, wordpress

i have a question regarding the efficiency of word press database structure.
My intended application will hold 3 custom post types and about 20-30 fields for each post type.
The basic structure of wordpress db requires me basically for each published post to have 30 insert actions once a new post is published ... is it the best way to go ?
if i will have 5000 posts (which will be there after 1 year) i will have a wp_post_meta of 150,000 rows ... how efficient is that will i experience performance issues ?

As i see it as the table will get longer and longer it will have an impact on its efficiency.

or am i getting it totally wrong ?

Comment: Good question, not a direct answer but take a look at this: http://www.onextrapixel.com/2010/05/19/a-detailed-look-into-wordpress-database-optimization/, Of course caching is recommended

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Table wp_postmeta has an index on the columns post_id and meta_key. Therefore a JOIN with the wp_posts table will be very fast an it will not need too many resources.

I do have databases with tables which hold more than 7 million rows. I do a lot of INSERT into and JOIN statements into these tables. But as I have an index on each important column, you don't really recognize, that these tables have millions of rows.

Comment: 7 million rows is nice :-) which site is it ?

Comment: No I don't use DB or HTML caching. I only minify JS and CSS and use DEFLATE to compress the response. However, I plan to use some sort of object caches for some queries in the future. But as it still runs quite fast, there is no need to right now. The site is the following: http://www.connecticum.de